# ffmpeg - convert audio (.au) to mp3

Tags: ffmpeg, mp3, ubuntu-14.04

i'm using ffmpeg (on Ubuntu) to convert a .au file to .mp3. File mp3 is created but have 0 byte.
That's my output:

```
$ ffmpeg -i 12345678.au output.mp3 

ffmpeg version 2.1.4 Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
  built on May  7 2014 01:40:43 with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1)
  configuration: 
  libavutil      52. 48.101 / 52. 48.101
  libavcodec     55. 39.101 / 55. 39.101
  libavformat    55. 19.104 / 55. 19.104
  libavdevice    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
  libavfilter     3. 90.100 /  3. 90.100
  libswscale      2.  5.101 /  2.  5.101
  libswresample   0. 17.104 /  0. 17.104
Guessed Channel Layout for  Input Stream #0.0 : mono
Input #0, au, from '12345678.au':
  Duration: 00:00:02.05, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 128 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s8 ([2][0][0][0] / 0x0002), 16000 Hz, mono, u8, 128 kb/s
Output #0, mp3, to 'output.mp3':
    Stream #0:0: Audio: none, 0 channels, 128 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (pcm_s8 -> ?)
Encoder (codec none) not found for output stream #0:0
```

The .au file is correct and I can open correctly. The .mp3 file is 0 byte or maybe corrupted (VLC can't play it).

Comment: It doesn't seem you are actually reading the information it's giving you.  "Encoder (codec none) not found for output stream #0:0" - It would appear you're lacking an MP3 encoder for it to use, or it's just set wrong.  More hints: `Output #0, mp3, to 'output.mp3': Stream #0:0: Audio: none, 0 channels` -- Note _0_ channels, and _NONE_ as the audio type.

Comment: Try specifying the codec by adding `-f mp3` before your `output.mp3`

Answer (score 3):

## The problem

You have no MP3 encoder enabled in `ffmpeg`. Your `configure` is blank, but you need `--enable-libmp3lame` (or `--enable-libshine` [not recommended]) to encode MP3 audio.

## How to fix

You can:

- recompile `ffmpeg` with libmp3lame support by following the step-by-step guide [How to Compile FFmpeg for Ubuntu](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu), or
- simply download a static build of `ffmpeg` via links on the [FFmpeg Download](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html#LinuxBuilds) page.

## Pipe alternative

You could pipe to `lame` instead:

```
ffmpeg -i input -f wav - | lame - output.mp3
```